# How to use the tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization() in custom training loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I went back to tensorflow after quite a while and it seems the landscape is completely changed.

However, previously I used to use `tf.contrib....batch_normalization` with the following in the training loop:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(cnn.loss, global_step=global_step)
```

But it seems, `contrib` is nowhere to be found and `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization` does not work the same way. Also, I couldn't find any training instruction in their [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization).

So, any information of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started using pyTorch. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As batch normalization behaves differently during training and inference, the `training` variable you pass into `call()` needs to be fed into the `BatchNormalization` layer.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def call(self, inputs, training=False):
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(inputs, training=training)
    return x
```